# Can a transistor replace a switch that closes ground to an input?

Tags: arduino, transistors, basic, camera

I've been browsing on Google for quite a bit now but couldn't find an answer.

I have a remote that triggers the shutter of a digital camera.

According to the schematics that I've found, the microswitch simply closes ground to the input of the camera's processor. Did I get this right?

Is there a way to replace SW1 and SW2 with a couple of transistors and control them with an Arduino or similar?

[image]

Comment: yes, google "transistor as low-side switch" and you'll see plenty of info. luckily it's easier to use a transistor to pull low than to pull high, so you have a lot of great options. I prefer n-channel FETs, but even a 2n2222 would probably work for you, they work on my Canon DSLRs. If in doubt, you can always use a reed relay.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use a transistor. But it is safer to use an optocoupler. Less risk of something going wrong and damaging your camera.

The optocoupler part number is not critical, something like a 4N35.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLjPL6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I've used this method in circuit bending and MIDIfying different toys and it works perfectly.