# How can I short three wires together using an Arduino?

Tags: transistors, relay, switching, camera

I have a wired shutter release for a DSLR camera. It has three wires within it (red, blue, and green). After disassembling it and doing some testing, I've determined the following:

| Wire | Voltage |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | Ground |
| Red | 3V DC |
| Green | 3.3V DC |

Connecting all three wires together opens the shutter and starts taking a photo. Then, when the wires are disconnected and reconnected, it closes the shutter and stops the photo (I'm using [bulb mode](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/12004)). Note that shorting blue to (green) focuses the camera (if autofocus is on). I only care about taking photos; I will never need to use autofocus with this shutter release for Reasons™.

Currently, I can do this by physically touching the stripped wires together. This works, but isn't exactly optimal. Instead, I'd like to be able to use my laptop (Windows 10/11) to take a photo with a shutter speed of ~n seconds.

Here are my ideas to achieve that:

- Use a couple [relays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay) to automate this. The two relays would be connected to a spare [Arduino Nano](https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-nano?selectedStore=us) I have, which I'd control over USB (serial).
- Use transistors. I'm a lot less confident with transistors, but they might work.

I think the code would need to do the following

- Wait for a serial message, and when it gets one, do the following:
- Close the relays (shorting the wires together)
- Wait *n* seconds (relays aren't instant, but it's "close enough" for my application"
- Open the relays (un-shorting the wires)

I need to be careful not to damage the camera, so I'm inclined to use a relay, as I'm more confident with them.

Is using a relay to do that the best option here, as I described above? Or is there a better way?

Comment: See previous similar Q&A: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/683197/can-a-transistor-replace-a-switch-that-closes-ground-to-an-input/683199#683199 Blue = Sleeve

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a relay is the simplest option. Use a DP (dual pole) relay rather than two separate relays.

More elegantly (but more complicated): two small solid-state relays with DC output or opto-isolators with BJT (transistor) output. You'll have to experiment on the polarity (I assume your wires are DC).